# Xpath can't click to button (Button id & value dynamically changes) Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

```
<form action="/assessments/1290/questions" id="questionform" method="post">
  <div class="happiness-reaction__item animated fadeIn selected">
    I often get upset over minor issues.
    <div class="inputs">

      <input id="choice_14832" value="14832" name="Answers[0].Choices" data-scv-reaction-id="strongly-disagree1" spellcheck="true" type="radio">
      <label class="u" for="choice_14832">
        <i class="sc-strongly-disagree"></i>
      </label>

      <input id="choice_14833" value="14833" name="Answers[0].Choices" data-scv-reaction-id="slightly-disagree1" spellcheck="true" type="radio">
      <label class="u" for="choice_14833">
        <i class="sc-slightly-disagree"></i>
      </label>

      <input id="choice_14834" value="14834" name="Answers[0].Choices" data-scv-reaction-id="none1" spellcheck="true" type="radio">
      <label class="u" for="choice_14834">
        <i class="sc-none"></i>
      </label>

      <input id="choice_14835" value="14835" name="Answers[0].Choices" data-scv-reaction-id="slightly-agree1" spellcheck="true" type="radio">
      <label class="u" for="choice_14835">
        <i class="sc-slightly-agree"></i>
      </label>

      <input id="choice_14836" value="14836" name="Answers[0].Choices" data-scv-reaction-id="strongly-agree1" spellcheck="true" type="radio">
      <label class="u" for="choice_14836">
        <i class="sc-strongly-agree"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
                 .....
```

I want to click on that radio buttons. Since ID & value etc change dynamically , I should be able to make a simple click via using XPATH , But i cant. I get no error but buttons stays  not-clicked.

[Check this picture please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7rRL.png)

So far I was not able to click by doing :

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='questionform']/div[1]/div/label[1]/i"));
button.click();
```

Edited: I added this info , just in case if some1 wants more detailed info about the page I am talking about. There must be a way to click that simple button without workarounds.

"I know that would be too much effort to ask , but you can go "supercareer.com" , and take Personality under assessments , and see what I am actually talking about. Note: doesnt have to be real mail , easy to register 1 click , no verification you can access the questions that I am talking about. Thats the only way to provide 100% info about my questions."

Comment: there should be only one div instead of two i guess

Comment: I am using FireBug to extract Xpath , I don't the mistake is there but i will double check. @santhosh kumar , I think if you slide the code to left , you will see the second div. ıt was not visible because of my copy paste

Comment: Ok got it.... Can you use chrome to extract the dynamic xpath and did you added some implicit wait?

Comment: I tried by also with implicit wait. Was not the solution. I will try with chrome-Driver and let you know.

Comment: Exactly which radio button (buttons) are you willing to click? Are all the choices same (all DISAGREE) ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do in cases like this is to find a "container" element that holds all the choices that you want to select from. In this case, we can use the question text to find the `DIV` that contains all 5 choices using XPath. From there, you can select the desired choice based on the classname of the `I` tag, e.g. `<i class="sc-strongly-agree">`. So provided the question text and the desired choice, we can make our selection.

In cases like this where you are likely use the same code over and over, you generally want to create a function to handle this. In addition, since you are selecting one of 5 choices repeatedly, I prefer to use an enum. You could use String but you would have to handle a potential wide variety of inputs and if someone ever misspells or somehow typos the string, the script fails. An enum makes it easy to select the desired choice because the IDE always shows you the choices making it a no-brainer. If you typo the enum, it won't compile... and it's always better to know earlier if a script is going to fail. An enum is also a container for those choices so that if the class names ever change, you change the class names in the enum and all scripts are fixed.

The function

```
public static void selectChoice(String question, Choices choice)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'happiness-reaction__item')][contains(.,'" + question + "')]//i[@class='" + choice.value() + "']")).click();
}
```

The enum

```
public enum Choices
{
    STRONGLYDISAGREE("sc-strongly-disagree"),
    SLIGHTLYDISAGREE("sc-slightly-disagree"),
    NONE("sc-none"),
    SLIGHTLYAGREE("sc-slightly-agree"),
    STRONGLYAGREE("sc-strongly-agree");

    private String value;

    Choices(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String value()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and here's how you call it

```
selectChoice("I often get upset over minor issues.", Choices.STRONGLYAGREE);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can't use ID and Value - use any other attribute. In your case 'data-scv-reaction-id' is a good option)

```
//*[@data-scv-reaction-id='strongly-disagree1']
```

Comment: I have 5 other questions to be selected on this page which also has same id + same values such as 'strongly-disagree1', so it doesn't help me to identify it as you said.

Comment: others have slightly-disagree1, slightly-agree1, none and etc values, not same. But if you have other elements on page, not only described - please provide full info in order we can give you correct answer

Comment: I know that would be too much effort to ask , but you can go "supercareer.com" , and take Personality under assessments , and see what I am actually talking about. Note: doesnt have to be real mail , easy to register 1 click , no verification you can access the questions that I am talking about. Thats the only way to provide 100% info about my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of tricks I use to keep my xpaths concise and more robust to change.

1. You can reference deeper elements than the one you want to select by adding `..` to the end of your xpath. For example I'd use the `<i class="x" />` to distinguish what to click and then use `..` to select the parent `<label />`
2. You can use `//` in the middle of an xpath as a wildcard to navigate through elements that aren't interesting.

Eg: `By.xpath("//form[@id='questionform']//i[@class='sc-strongly-disagree']/..")`

Answer (score 0):

So let's understand it this way:

1. Each question has a reaction section.
2. Each reaction section has a multiple reaction buttons/icons.

I've faced such a scenario and it needs to be handled in the following manner:

```
public void reactToQuestion(String question, String reaction) {
    // Get the question element
    // For eg. question = "I always complete all aspects of my work."
    By locQuestion = By.xpath("//*[text()='" + question + "']");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(locQuestion);

    // Get the parent 'div' container of the question
    WebElement container = element.findElement("..");

    // Get reaction RELATIVELY to the question
    // reaction = 'strongly-disagree1', 'slightly-disagree1', etc.
    By locReaction = By.xpath(".//*[@class='inputs']/input[@data-scv-reaction-id=" + reaction + "]");
    WebElement reaction = container.findElement(locReaction);
    reaction.click();

}
```

Please try and let me know if there are any issues.

Good luck.

Comment: I did not try it , but my problem is also this , U cant locate questions by texts  , because questions will come 5 by 5 by randomazing. only thing that doe'nt change is the locations of the elements (xpaths).  Basically, every page , I get 5 random questions from a pool of 20. (questions are same , but since it is randomized , it is hard to locate it by text)

Comment: As per your problem statement defined, the solution requested was 'locating emotion icons'. You can modify the method to locate questions in any manner. But the crux of the matter remains that you can ONLY locate emotion icons RELATIVE to the 'located question'.

Comment: Unfortunatly so far , I couldnt solve this problem. I even tried different webdriver / versions , since I did not have any problem to locate any container or element. Anyways , If there are some1 who is willing to ake their hands dirty I would like to give a test account.

Comment: Sure thing. Post a test project on github or message me on linkedin/twitter. Details on my SO profile page.

Answer (score 0):

As a general xpath, first input from question, it could be something like:

```
//form[@id='questionform']/div//input
```

If you need any `input` for certain question:

```
//form[@id='questionform']/div[contains(@class, 'happiness-reaction')]//input
```

If you need certain answer for a certain question then:

```
//form[@id='questionform']/div[contains(@class, 'happiness-reaction')]//input[@data-scv-reaction-id='strongly-disagree1']
```

If you need to add params for question and/or answer then:

```
//form[@id='questionform']/div[contains(@class, 'part_of_question_class')]//input[@data-scv-reaction-id='desired_answer_attr']
```

These params can be stored in an array/list or any form you like.

All these can be done in css also:

```
form#questionform>div input
form#questionform>div[class*=happiness-reaction] input
form#questionform>div[class*=happiness-reaction] input[data-scv-reaction-id='strongly-disagree1']
```

You get the idea.

Comment: I have'nt try to solve the problem as your last suggestion (css) , but still unable to click it by Xpath. I have tried your xpath formats too , whatever I do , selenium acts like "driver was successfully find & clicked the element" .